# NodeJS: Adding channels to a Socket.IO server without restarting

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

**Edit:** This question was asked due to inadequate knowledge of the `EventMachine`.

With the Socket.IO interface, I can multiplex connections with "channels". How would I start a Socket.IO server, but add channels without having to stop/start the server?

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

var chat = io
  .of('/chat')
  .on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('a message', {
        that: 'only'
      , '/chat': 'will get'
    });
    chat.emit('a message', {
        everyone: 'in'
      , '/chat': 'will get'
    });
  });

var news = io
  .of('/news')
  .on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('item', { news: 'item' });
  });
```

This code example from Socket.IO shows starting the server, then creating two channels called `chat` and `news`. What I if I started the server with `chat`, but wanted to add `news` without any interruption to `chat`? How would I add the channel?

Comment: Can you give me an example of why you would want to start the server with chat, but not with news? I need a better understanding of your actual use case. Otherwise, Vadim is correct, you just call `io.of('channel')` to create another channel, there is no need to restart.

Comment: I would start the Socket.IO server, and add instances of a process with a script, each binding to a channel that is created when the process is created. Otherwise please explain how I would externally (like from another script) add a channel to a preexisting Socket.IO server.

Comment: So are you running multiple node instances? I'm not sure what you mean by "add instances of a process with a script". Are you just trying to setup multiple channels in different files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need restart your server to add namesapaces. Just start using new namespace. In your example both namespaces (`chat` and `news`) created after server start.

Comment: Do you mean like, allow a user input for a new namespace and then use that?